# Set parent div to hidden if it's child div is hidden

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using angular and I need to control the visibility of div using ng-show directive. Consider below dom tree:

```
<div ng-show="var1">
  <div ng-switch="condition">
    <div ng-switch-when=true>
      <div ng-show="var2"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <div ng-show="var3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it's fine when the `var1` itself is false. But when `var1` is true and either of `var2` or `var3` depending on `condition` are also false the div is actually empty but it does show on the webpage because `var1` is true. I want the parent div to inherit `display:none` if the child is also hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use a simple AND and OR statement, this way:

```
<div ng-show="var1 && (var2 || var3)">
  <div ng-switch="condition">
    <div ng-switch-when=true>
      <div ng-show="var2"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <div ng-show="var3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so your actual parent div will show only if one of the child is "enabled" and visible.

P.S.

Careful, you got a typo on the second line, `ng-shitch`

Answer (score 0):

You can make change the condition as `ng-show= var1 && (var2 || var 3)` for `div` so that your parent div will be shown only when any of `var2` or`var3` are set to true like this

```html
<div ng-show="var1 && (var2 || var3)">
  <div ng-shitch="condition">
    <div ng-switch-when=true>
      <div ng-show="var2"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <div ng-show="var3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var1` is actually an independent necessary condition so can't eliminate that

Comment: @MehulAgrawal then you can use combination of and and or. Updated my answer for the same